# Python3.6 and CSHELL Script on Centos 7 - need to step through prompts

Tags: python-3.6, centos7, csh

I am currently dealing with a cshell script that I need to run on my servers, I cannot modify the cshell script.  I wanted to automate running the script, which I have succeeded in launching the script, but the script has questions to be answered - examples:

Choose 1 for Linux, Choose 2 for Windows, or 3 to exit:

What is the system hostname:

etc.....

I want to be able to answer these questions through the python script.  I have searched the standard Google searches, but I am unfamiliar with the results nothing seems to quite be the answer - does anyone know of any modules that can perform this function, with some good examples that I can see to help with the comprehension of putting this together, any recommendations or suggestions are appreciated? Thanks for your consideration!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The canonical tool to drive an interactive tool is `expect`.
See https://core.tcl.tk/expect/index for more information.

Your expect script, given your example, would be something like:

```
expect -re "Choose 1.*exit:"
send -- "1\r"
expect "hostname:"
send -- "$hostname\r"
```

Once you've got the expect script working you can call this simply from Python.

Comment: I will take a look at this - I believe what I want to look at is pexpect which is a python module.  Hopefully it will do the same thing and keep my script more integrated - will let you know:    https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/